# Why is JSON data sent from server to browser undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, http

I want to make a request to my server with fetch(), and have data returned to be used in the front end app.

here is my route:

```
    app.get('/game-data', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ data: "test-data" })
})
```

and here is my request:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('/game-data', {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application / json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            response.json()
        })
        .then(myJson => {
            console.log(myJson)
        })
})
```

I can see the response object in the first console log, but response.json(), or response.text() are returning undefined.

Please help me see what I am missing!

Comment: Because you don't _return_ the promise `response.json()` returns, it's not part of the promise chain.

Comment: Just be aware that `response.json()` doesn't return JSON (it's not super important, but worth knowing). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value to use it in another .then

```
.then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! The example I was looking at used an implicit return.  I put the .json() on a new line so I could console log, so I also needed to explicitly return.   thanks to all who commented :-)

Comment: I am pleased that I can help you. Happy hacking!